# Rule condition to check which language is used by the visitor?

Tags: rules

I have a multilingual website (English, Spanish).

Is there any way to create a rule condition to compare the language used by the visitor against a fixed value?

The condition would something like: if language is **English** then go ahead with the actions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seemed like a useful thing to have.

I created a patch for Rules, adding this functionality. I posted it [in the Rules issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/1472316). That seemed better than providing the code directly here, as this way you can still use it anyway that suits you, yet it may actually get into core Rules.

Also see this question, ["How do I add a new condition in Rules 2?"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18186/how-do-i-add-a-new-condition-in-rules-2).

Comment: I was about to do a quick write up for this functionality, yours was pretty much what i was aiming for. I'd do a +2 for adding it as a patch for Rules if I could.

Comment: Awesome that you added this as a patch to Rules.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are two ways for that:

### **1- The easy one :**

Add new **condition** select **Data comparison** and in the parameter:

> Parameter: **Data to compare**: [site:current-page:language], **Data value**: English

[image]

---

### **2- The Hard one:**

```
/*
* Implements hook_rules_condition_info().
*/

function MODULE_NAME_rules_condition_info() {
 $conditions = array();

 $conditions['MODULE_NAME_check_current_user_language'] = array(
   'label' => t('Current user language'),
   'group' => t('YOUR GROUP NAME'),
   'parameter' => array(
     'language' => array(
       'type' => 'token',
       'label' => t('Language'),
       'description' => t('Select language that will be compared against the
user current language.'),
       'options list' => 'entity_metadata_language_list',
       'default value' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
     ),
   ),
 );

 return $conditions;
}
```

Then:

```
/*
*  Compare site current language with required language
*/

function MODULE_NAME_check_current_user_language($required_language) {
 global $language;

 return $language->language == $required_language;
}
```

Don't forget to clear the cache.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a new condition in a module, using the following implementation of `hook_rules_condition_info()`.

```
function mymodulename_rules_condition_info() {
  return array(
    'check_current_user_language' => array(
      'label' => t('Language for current user'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'string' => array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'label' => t('Language to check'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ); 
}

function mymodule_check_current_user_language($string) {
  global $user, $language_content;

  return ($user->language == $string);
}
```

Comment: And what do you do when the german language is added?

Answer (score 1):

One of the rules maintainers, fago, has a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1422996) under development (started recently and marked as "needs work") that adds a variety of internationalization features to rules, including functions for checking the language of users as well as setting languages for rules themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this function in the I18n bundle for translating.
In rules use date comparison

Answer (score -1):

You can try to accomplish this adding additional field to profile and using 2 different rules.

1st will set the value of the field, using [this](http://drupal.org/node/277675) [functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/language/7)

2nd will compare the profile field value using account:profile_lang data selector

Comment: I assume this requires use of eval()?